# Boto3 connection in CircleCI raises NoCredentialsError

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, circleci, aws-secrets-manager

I am having a fun problem with CircleCI build runner's ability to connect to AWS to run tests for me. I have just turned this off for now as these tests are optional just to test the actual connection to AWS but I would like to figure out what is going on!

I am very familiar with the [AWS configuration documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) and use AWS Profiles on my local machine. When running these tests locally I have no problem with them running so the credentials work and I have the proper IAM permissions set for the testing account.

I am hosting [my code](https://github.com/gdoermann/supersecret) on GitHub and trying to run the build with CircleCI. The build fails due to a `NoCredentialsError`.  I have tried running the `aws-cli-cred-setup` orb to configure AWS before running my build, I have tried saving a `~/.aws/config` file with a default profile and then setting my profile to `default`, setting the standard environment variables:

- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION

Nothing works!

I was getting an error saying the region was not set so I added a default keyword arg:

```
    def connect(self) -> BaseClient:
        """
        Connect to AWS Secrets Manager to the default aws session
        :return: client
        """
        if self.client:
            return self.client
        import boto3
        self.aws_kwargs.setdefault('region_name', os.environ.get('AWS_REGION', 'us-east-1'))

        self.client = boto3.client(self.SERVICE_NAME, **self.aws_kwargs)
        self.__client_created = True
        return self.client
```

Full code can be [found here](https://github.com/gdoermann/supersecret/blob/main/supersecret/parser.py#L39).

The `aws_kwargs` is empty when running in the CircleCI. I want the build to use the default environment variables I set in my build setup so I don't have to complicate the code.

Any advice would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mre], if your code works fine on its own but fails with CircleCI, provide the configuration for that to enable us to reproduce your problem.